# Grouping by Name in Query Formula not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

So I am using a query function to count the number of instances a particular name appears in column A of another sheet, and display that result in Column B of this sheet with the respective name in Column A. Here is the function:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(Attendance!A:A&{"",""},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Count'",1))
```

The problem is, while it works for the most part, some of the names appear twice, for instance Fred Jones appears as:

```
Col A | Col B

Fred Jones |  5

Fred Jones |  2
```

I have looked at the names, and there is no discernible difference between them, I do not understand why it is not grouping. Is there a way I can use wildcard or something to get Google to combine the names if they are nearly identical? Any help would be appreciated, thanks as always.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM({Attendance!A:A}), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)'Count'", 1))
```

Comment: thank you Player0, that worked out great, I totally forgot about the Trim feature!